# Get all Columns of One table having one column which has to derive data from another table corresponding to its data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Consider a table

PRODUCTSTABLE

```
product_id | product_name | product_country
1          | ABC          | 1    
2          | DEF          | 3    
3          | ASD          | 2    
4          | JGH          | 3    
5          | WER          | 2
```

COUNTRY TABLE

```
country_id | country_name
1          | Japan
2          | China
3          | Uganda
4          | France
5          | United States
```

I want to get results like as this query would produce

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTSTABLE;
```

The only difference would be in the third column 'product_country', instead of number respective Country name referenced from the second table must come.

Thank you.

Comment: yes, I did it. :) :) thanks Guys.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to join both tables using `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.product_id,
        a.product_name,
        b.country_name
FROM    products a
        INNER JOIN country b
            ON a.product_country = b.country_ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT 
  A.Product_ID, A.Product_Name, B.Country_Name 
FROM PRODUCTSTABLE A 
LEFT JOIN Country_Table B on A.Product_Country = B.Country_ID
```

try this article: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)